# vscode not finding type hinting for npm mssql via @types/mssql

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've been beating my head against a wall for hours on this one, it should be simple. I have a project where the node_modules are installed in a nested folder. This is a Node project with a tsconfig.json in the project root. It's not a typescript project, but I can't use `typeRoots` in `jsconfig.json` so I'm forced to use a tsconfig.json. I'm trying to get vscode to provide type hinting for the `mssql` package, but no matter what happens it's showing up in vscode as type `any`. I'm able to properly get type hinting for mocha (describe, it), node (assert), and the functions declared within the project. I'm getting type hinting for the `p-memoize` project when I require it (that uses d.ts file located in the project, not in @types). The difference here is that with `mssql` I'm using require() and it's failing with that.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl" : ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "typeRoots": ["containers/shared/node_modules/@types/"],
        "paths" : {
            "*": ["containers/shared/node_modules/*"],
            "@simpleview/*" : ["../../containers/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a code file with the following:

```
const mssql = require("mssql");
```

mssql is resolving as type `any`.

In my package.json I have the latest version of both `mssql` and `@types/mssql`:

```
"@types/mssql": "4.0.7",
"mssql": "6.2.1",
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is the @types/mssql project bugged, but if so, what exactly is wrong with it so I could submit a PR to fix it?